# VBA - IE GetElementByID not working

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, vbe

I'm having some trouble with entering a text in a search box when after I what I think to be the correcet ID tag is. I got the ID from the page's source code. I've done this before with other websites. Can someone please help me out? Is there another way to do this?

```
Sub FileUpload()

Dim IEexp as Object
IEexp.visible = True
IEexp.Navigate ("www.example.com")

'this is where the problem
IEexp.Document.GetElementByID("step1_id_bean_newSupportingDoc_description").Value _ 
= "monthly update"

End Sub
```

I get a "Automation Error The Object invoked has disconnected from its clients"

Source Code where I pulled the ID from:

```
<td class="Label">Description</td>
  <td class="Data"><input type="text" name="bean.newSupportingDoc.description" size="60" maxlength="250" value="" id="step1_id_bean_newSupportingDoc_description" class="NoBorder"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the document to load before trying to access the input element?

Comment: i ran it locally and i waited for the page load event to happen and i get iwebbrowser2 error

Comment: Yes, I've run it in break mode so I wait until the page completely loads and i still get that error.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Set IEexp = New InternetExplorerMedium` you don't have to change the settings in your Internet Options. It automatically instantiates the IE object with Medium Integrity Application settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Do Until IEexp.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop



IEexp.Document.getElementById("username").Value = "Monthly update"


IEexp.Document.getElementById("password").Value = FilePth
```